# Building Eclipse project using Angengine, and convert into Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine

I am a newbie in game development. And I have a project which is like other normal android app - it has left menu, action bar, and other views. However, inside the project there is also a small game. Let me briefly describe the game:

It is a game of a character moving from the bottom to the top of the screen, using accelerometer. There are some obstacles sitting in the screen blocking the character from moving, and it has to avoid those obstacles. When it hits the obstacle, it simply moves to the original position, and the game restart. When the character reaches the top, the screen zoom out with some animation. A menu is pop up asking if the player wants to move to the next level or quit the game.

<s>My question is,</s>

1. is it necessary to build the game using Andengine?
2. And if I want to use Andengine, could I build only the game part using Andengine, and the rest of the project using Android Studio?
3. Could I build the game using Android Studio?

Let me edit my question:

So with Android Studio, I could have part of the app not using Andengine, and only the game part using Andengine, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use Android Studio for the entire project to simply things in the long run.

Comment: OK, I think so. I can find many tutorials about building games using Eclipse (For Andengine), but not many about building games using Android Studio. I think I should switch to Android Studio then. Thanks. So with Android Studio, I could have part of the app not using Andengine, and only the game part using Andengine, right?

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine does not really have Gradle support unlike LibGDX.

Here is a project on Github that supports it: https://github.com/heinrisch/AndEngine-Kitkat-Gradle.

You notice in the `build.gradle` they are bringing `AndEngine` in as a project and compiling it as a dependency.